# How to change Facebook get code with own customization

Tags: html, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I have created site using HTML and Bootstrap. I have got code from follow button from Facebook Like.

```
 <div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/kenshinkan" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

This code works for Facebook default follow button. But I have already created 
 Looks Liks

```
2,367 Followers
```

My code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 two-left">
    <span>2,367</span>
    <p>Followers</p>
</div>
```

How to change follow button code to  link to my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Social Plugins cannot be customized - only with the settings they provide. If you want to create your own Followers count, you will have to create an App for that and use the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

...although, i believe you can´t even get the number of followers for a user with the Graph API, so there may be no way to achieve this.

Creating your own follower button may not be possible at all, and it would most likely not be allowed anyway. Facebook wants you to use official plugins, so people know it´s from Facebook.

Comment: oh thank you@if i create new app with Graph API  can i   use my Own follower Button ?

Comment: you may just get the follower count - but there is not even a field for that in the user table. your own follower button may not be possible at all.